# Derivatives - Show equality

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $y(x)$ be defined implicitly by $G(x,y(x))=0$, where $G$ is a given two-variable function. Show that if $y(x)$ and $G$ are differentiable, then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}}}{\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}} ,  \text{ if } \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} \neq 0$$

$$$$

- First of all, what does it mean that $y(x)$ is defined implicitly by $G(x,y(x))=0$ ??
- I have done the following:

  Let $f(x)=x$. Then $G(x,y(x))=G(f(x), y(x))=H(x)$.

  We have that $G(x,y(x))=0 \Rightarrow H(x)=0$.

  $H(x)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{H(x)}{dx}=0$

  From the chain rule we have the following:

  $$\frac{H(x)}{dx}=\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{f}}\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{dx} \\  \Rightarrow 0=\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{dx} \\  \Rightarrow 0=\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{dx} \\  \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}} \\ \overset{ \text{ if } \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}\ \neq 0 }{\Longrightarrow }\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}}}{\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}}$$

  Is this correct ?? Could I improve something ??

**EDIT1:**

I have to find a similar formula if $y_1$, $y_2$ are defined implicitly by $$G_1(x, y_1(x), y_2(x))=0 \\ G_2(x, y_1(x), y_2(x))=0$$

I have the following:

From the chain we have the following:

$$\frac{dG_1}{dx}=\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{x}} \frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx} \Rightarrow 0=\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx}$$

Similar, we get $$0=\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx}$$

Is it correct so far??

Hw could I continue??

$$$$

**EDIT2:**

We have that $$0=\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}= -\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{x}} -\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx} \ \ \ \ (*) \\ 0=\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{dy_2}{dx}=-\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{x}} -\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx} \\ \Rightarrow  \frac{dy_2}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}}{\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_2}}} \\ (*) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}= -\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}}{\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_2}}} \Rightarrow  \frac{dy_1}{dx}=\frac{ -\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_2}} \frac{\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{x}} +\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_1}} \frac{dy_1}{dx}}{\frac{\partial{G_2}}{\partial{y_2}}}}{\frac{\partial{G_1}}{\partial{y_1}}}$$

Is this correct?? Could I improve something?? Could we write the last equality in a simplified way??

Answer (score 1):

"$y(x)$ is defined implicitly by $G(x,y(x))=0$" means that for each $x$, $y(x)$ is defined to be "the" solution to $G(x,y(x))=0$. This is only an implicit definition because it doesn't give a recipe for calculating $y$. I put the word "the" in scare quotes because typically there are several solutions, and this $y$ is only defined on a neighborhood of a particular solution. ($G(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ is a great example for how to see this; the two functions you get come from the top and bottom semicircles.)

Your derivation of the derivative is correct (minus a minor typo). In the one variable situation ($x,y \in \mathbb{R}$), this is just implicit differentiation as you probably saw in Calculus I.

Comment: I haven't really understood what it means that $y(x)$ is defined implicitly by $G(x,y(x))=0$... Could you explain it further to me?? 
$$$$ 
At the beginning I have set $f(x)=x$. Could I show it also without using this substitution?? @Ian

Comment: @MaryStar You didn't really need to introduce $f$ (nor $H$, really, provided you are OK with the symbols $\frac{dG}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ both being in use), but it wasn't wrong to do so. Anyway, maybe it would make more sense in an example. Think of the equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$. Given an $x \in [-1,1]$ and a choice of the bottom or top circle, this specifies $y$, but it doesn't actually tell you what $y$ is explicitly. You have to solve the equation to find $y$. Since you have to solve the equation, $y$ is only given implicitly.

Comment: @MaryStar The *explicit* function for the top half of the circle is $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. But again this explicit form is not given directly from the equation, and actually in most situations it is impossible to write it down.

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it ?? @Ian

Comment: @MaryStar You just have to solve the linear system.

Comment: I edited again my post... Could you take a look at it?? @Ian